# How to correct deflated p value distribution from qqplot in PWAS/GWAS

Tags: p-value, gwas

I'm conducting regression analysis using R of the ability of several hundred proteins (and other covariates) to predict ventricle volume in a human sample. As is common in GWAS/PWAS research, I plotted the expected vs. observed p values of each protein to check their overall distribution. As the plot below shows, there is significant deflation from the expected distribution of p values. I found that calculating standard error estimates is a potential way around this, which worked for some of my DVs but not for ventricle volume.

I wondered a) why calculating robust standard error estimates did not correct the deflation and b) what I can do to correct this problem?

[image: qqplot of expected vs. observed log-10 p-values for PWAS analysis of ventricle volume]